# jQuery image transition plugin

Tags: jquery

I'm looking for some simple crossbrowser plugin/function that could change one image to other with some smooth effect (fadeIn, fadeOut or opacity is not an option), code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
imgtimer = setInterval(function() {

  // this is something what I'm looking for:
 var from = $('.visible');
 var to = $('.visible').next('img');
 changeimg(from,to,effect);
  // some function that could be able to hide one image
  // and show other with some effect.

}, 5000);
</script>

<div id="images">
  <img src="img_01.jpg" class="visible" />
  <img src="img_02.jpg" />
  <img src="img_03.jpg" />
</div>
```

Any ideas? I just can find any plugin that would look nice. I don't need any complex sliders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://canvasimg.sjeiti.com/

This set of plugins weighs in at about 22k minified (less if you strip out transitions/easings that you don't need)

It provides these transitions: fade, zoom, wipe, fold, flip, blinds, circle, square, clock, wave, particles, noise, simplexNoise, drip.

It provides these easings: Linear, Quadratic, Cubic, Quartic, Quintic, Sinusoidal, Exponential, Circular, Elastic, Back, Bounce.

You can use an image with a background image.
You get the best results using a canvas element (canvas is cross-browser for all modern browsers/android and even pre-ie9 compatible with a shim)

Comment: Hi, can you please post some example code, how to use this script? Because its not working for me, I'm using it like: `CIMG.tween( existingIMG, nextIMG, 1000, CIMG.transition.fade ,TWEEN.Easing.Quintic.EaseInOut, { callback:function(){ }});`

Answer (score 0):

The plugins are too heavy to just make an slider, I did something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/k9e5f/8/ it can give you some ideas to develop your own slider.

I just use one image and one div like this:

```
<div id="background_container">
    <img id="changer" />
</div>
```

Just take a look at that slider, it works with all images you want. I made it myself ;)

Comment: Yes the plugins really are too heavy. But your answer is also not exactly what I am looking for, and it uses `fadeIn` `fadeOut`. What I need is function `changeimg(from,to,effect);` that could change one image to another with some effect.